# Search Builder One of parameters is not of the type MysqlColumnName

Tags: search-builder

Drupal 7.43 / CIVICRM 4.7.7

I am trying to find contacts with no emails (any type eg/ Home, Other) using Search Builder. Using either IS EMPTY or IS NULL, I end up with no result but get a DB error.
Viz:  Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment.
One of parameters (value: Home-email) is not of the type MysqlColumnName

It doesn't seem to matter what operator I use, the result is the same.
Please help. Ian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried to replicate this problem on the demo site but couldn't.

I would recommend upgrading to Civi 4.7.9, and if you still have the problem, you can do two things:

- Try to replicate it on the demo server (demo.civicrm.org).  If you can't, the issue is most likely in the configuration.
- The "DB Error" isn't really enough info to go on.  So you can go to **Administer menu » System Settings » Debugging and Error Handling**, and set "Debug mode" and "backtrace" to "yes".  That will give you a much more detailed error.  Updating your question with that info will let folks provide much more detailed information!

Comment: Thanks, I will follow your advice and upgrade next week. Thanks so much, Ian